# Cant use groups in a virtual user

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I am trying to set up some virtual users in puppet.  The basic users work fine, but for some reason when I try to add "groups" to the user definition the run fails.

Here is the basic virtual user config...

```
class users::virtual {
    define localuser ($uid,$gid) {

            user { $title:
                    ensure  =>      "present",
                    uid     =>      $uid,
                    gid     =>      $gid,
                    shell   =>      "/bin/bash",
                    home    =>      "/home/$title",
                    comment =>      $realname,
                    managehome =>   true,
            }
      }
}
```

and here is a user called out...

```
class my::users {
include users::virtual
    @users::virtual::localuser { "jdehnert": 
    uid =>  "504",
    gid =>  "users",
    groups  =>  ["wheel", "rvm"],
    require =>  Group["rvm"],
    }
}
```

the init.pp is...

```
class people {
include my::users
realize (
    Users::Virtual::Localuser["jdehnert"],
    )
}
```

When I run a test --noop on a client, I get this message on the client...

```
# puppetd --test --noop
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter groups at /etc/puppet/manifests/users/users.pp:7 on node dev-web-1.
```

and this one on the server...

```
Aug 23 04:29:38 centos63 puppet-master[21713]: Invalid parameter groups at /etc/puppet/manifests/users/users.pp:7 on node dev-web-1
```

If I pull the "groups" line out, this config works just fine.

I also discovered that if I just make a plain user resource I can pass the "groups" parameter just fine.  So, why does it not work with a virtual user?

Thanks,

James "Zeke" Dehnert
jdehnert@dehnert.com

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding something here:

```
@users::virtual::localuser { "jdehnert": 
uid =>  "504",
gid =>  "users",
groups  =>  ["wheel", "rvm"],
require =>  Group["rvm"],
}
```

Above you are declaring a `localuser`, which is thus defined:

```
define localuser ($uid,$gid) {
```

That means the *only* parameters it receives are `uid`, `gid` and the metaparameters (such as `require`). Since `groups` is not a metaparameter nor, obviously, is it `uid` or `gid`, then it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  There is still a lot about puppet that confuses me.   If I was to use define...   localuser ($uid,$gid, $groups)  then I should be able to declare them I suspect.

Comment: @jdehnert Correct. You can declare `undef` as default for `$groups`, and then you don't need to specify it always. Unfortunately, you'll need an `if` below to select between a `user` declaration with `groups`, and one without. Note too that if you do not pass `groups` to the `user`, it will not have one.